# Употребляется ли так: «бунтуй что-то»?

Tags: глаголы

Как правильно сказать:

празднуй праздник – бунтуй бунт,
празднуй день рождение – бунтуй день рождение,
празднуй взросление – бунтуй взросление? Празднуй свою жизнь - бунтуй недовольство...

Употребляется ли так: «бунтуй что-то»?
Ведь "празднуй что-то" употребляется.

Answer (score 4):

Лучше: справлять праздник; Празднуй день рождениЯ. Не совсем ясно, что значит " бунтуй день рождениЯ".

Бунтуй - глагол непереходный, не требует после себя дополнение. 
БУНТОВАТЬ, -тую, -туешь; нсв.
1.
Поднимать бунт (1.Б.; 1 зн.),
участвовать в бунте.
2. (св. взбунтовать). кого-что.
Возбуждать недовольство, призывать к решительным действиям против кого-, чего-л. Хватит народ б.!
3. Разг.
Выражать большое недовольство; упорно не соглашаться, протестовать. Б. против перевода на новое место работы. * Опять моя старуха бунтует: Уж не хочет быть она дворянкой (Пушкин).
4. Трад.-поэт.
Бушевать, волноваться. Кровь, душа бунтует
(о крайне возбуждённом состоянии человека). * В груди твоей бунтуют страсти (Лермонтов).

ВЗБУНТОВАТЬ, -тую, -туешь; взбунтованный; -ван, -а, -о; св. (нсв. бунтовать). кого-что.
Побудить, склонить к бунту, к неповиновению. В. народ.

Comment: >Бунтуй - глагол непереходный, не требует после себя дополнение  
  
Не "не требует", а просто не позволяет иметь доолнения в нужной форме (винительный без предлога).  
Переходные глаголы тоже не ***тербуют***, а только ***допускают*** такое идополнение.

Answer (score 0):

Бунт - это состояние души под воздействием негативных факторов. Поэтому душа бунтует по поводу, а не против. Действие организма (в частном случае человека) с целью устранения негативного фактора люди назвали "бунт против", при этом часто не озвучивается "за что"... "Опять моя старуха бунтует (уже против состояния дворянства за состояние царицы)...". Можно взбунтовать кого-то (против чего-то, чтобы...), но нельзя взбунтовать чего-то, в т.ч.: день, дождь, рождение, сам бунт.

Праздник (праздное время, день) - время без производительной работы. Можно поднять ложку с кашей и донести ее до рта, но варить в этот день кашу нельзя. Этот обычай восходит к библейским временам. Праздные дни (праздники) учреждались в честь знаменательных событий: исхода евреев из Египта, рождения Христа, Великой Октябрьской революции и пр.
В такие дни люди только веселились, а не работали. В дальнейшем понятие праздника распространилось на дни, не связанные с прекращением работ, но несущие повод для веселья: дни шахтеров, метростроевцев, рождений родственников и т.п. Поэтому правильно говорить: праздную по поводу дня рождения (десантника и пр.), но из-за лени и ради удобства предложение сократили до "празднуем Рождество (новоселье и пр.)". Справлять праздник - правильное выражение, т.к. подразумевает проведение праздного дня сообразно своим представлениям.